# Is there ever a reason that a SQL job should be owned by anyone other than sa?

Tags: sql-server

Put differently, should I always set the job owner to sa for a SQL job, even though it defaults to the user who created it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any jobs that are owned by a user will cease to run if that user is disabled or deleted. The jobs may also not run if there is an Active Directory problem at run time. Brent Ozar has an article about this on his website:
http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/jobs-owned-by-user-accounts/

Comment: That's a good point.  Which is why I keep "sql authentication" hanging around for a few of these needs.  I would probably create a dedicated job_owner (sql authentication) account.  I get a little scared of letting 'sa' own everything, mainly because sa can delete/drop do anything.

Comment: Yes it was actually a SQLPASS presentation of his that I watched (about sp_Blitz) that led me to ask this question.  I want to make this change as many of my jobs are owned by non-sa accounts.  I was just making sure there wasn't some reason to avoid doing so.

Comment: @granadaCoder I usually use SQL Agent Proxies to change the permissions of a job step. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to bear with me.  Because I'm going by memory.

Looking at some old scripts, I have this code.

select @jobOwnerNameVeryImportantToSetCorrectly = 'someSqlAuthenticatonUser'

Now.  In my scenario, I allowed a non 'sa' user to schedule and run the jobs.
Thus why I made the owner a non 'sa' user.

The question I think to answer is, "who runs the jobs".  If it is always 'sa', then its not an issue.

But, if you want a non 'sa' account to run it, then how is a less privileged account going to run a job owned by the super-mack-daddy account?

My test would be.

1. Create a job.  Let 'sa' own it.
2. Create a temp sql-authentication account.
3. Login to the database as this sql-authentication account.
4. See if you can run the job.

My memory is saying "the lesser account won't be able to".  However, I dealt with jobs on Sql Server 2005.  So even if I remember correctly for 2005, it may not be the same for 2008 or 2008R2.

But I remember having issues with this.  And thus my variable declaration:

select @jobOwnerNameVeryImportantToSetCorrectly = 'someSqlAuthenticatonUser'

Comment: Does job ownership affect who the job runs as?  I thought it was always the SQL Agent account that ran the job regardless of the owner.

Answer (score 0):

I read Brent Ozar's article as well and am in a similar situation where there are a lot of jobs not owned by SA that are enabled.  From what I have researched, I haven't found any compelling reason **NOT** to change the ownership to 'SA' but two good reasons mentioned above why you should.

You don't have to worry about them not being able to run from this change.  The only two things I would be cautious about are:
 1) Jobs that you **run** as SA and 
 2) If you are coming into an environment, enabling jobs that have been disabled after you've made this change.

Why someone would ever do those two things, IDK but you can always back up msdb and then test these changes in a dev or training server.  Just note the jobs that you change in case something unexpected happens.